# Multiple libGDX views in a single Android activity

Tags: android, performance, libgdx

I'm interested in using [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) within broader android / iOS applications. The basic idea is to implement a common, core library of graphical views which could be basic games, models, data visualizations, etc.

The simple wire-frame below better explains the scenario. The text elements must be native views in android / iOS - only views 1, 2 and 3 must be rendered by libGDX.

[image: Android application concept view]

I have tested the ability to add ApplicationListeners as views in Android thus far with the code below:

```
    // Create a libGDX view
    View view = initializeForView(new ApplicationListenerImpl());

    // Add it to the layout
    layout.addView(view);
```

I am however having some trouble with multiple views, which could be the result of shared resources in the libGDX implementation. I could not find any useful resources describing this use of the library.

*Additionally*: Performance is of course important. Preferably, thread-safe libGDX resources must be shared across all views to reduce redundancy. But each view must have its own data and controller.

Is libGDX suitable for this scenario? Or are there alternative libraries better suited to this scenario?

Comment: Maybe you want different sub views within one libgdx application instead? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2220 this might help maybe.

Comment: I have not tested that option, but I am hesitant to. It is important for the text views to be native to each platform for various reasons. The intention is simply to have injectable libgdx views - the locations must remain arbitrary and platform-dependent.

Comment: Okay, if a native environment is a requirement for the views, then my solution does not fit here.